# Reusing the same viewController on top of the navigationStack in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

For my app project i have created a tableView that show a wine including, rating reviews, tasting notes and all sorts of data in each section. In the last section the user is shown two similar wines, once pushed it is the purpose to reUse the current viewController, and throw it onto the navigation stack as the user might browse another wine inside that viewController and so forth.

How would you go about, reUsing the same viewController. Since building infinite numbers of the same viewController in storyboards seems abit rookie to me. Thanks all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use storyboard, there is a hack (a bit dirty).

1. You should add button to view controller. But not to the view of
   view controller, you should add it to the top section (top bar) of
   your view controller.
2. Then you add segue from this button to this very view controller.
3. Now you may use this segue from code (performSegue...)

Comment: This is indeed working. But the segue behaviour is wierd. Once the user press similar wine they segue as purposed, but if they choose to segue again from the new view they are showen the segue motion twice, and this effect adds up with 2^n. Do you know a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Storyboards` and reuse the `ViewController` with no problem.
In the `Storyboard` use the `Storyboard ID` in the `identity inspector`, Add a unique ID to the `ViewController`.

After that it's pretty simple, you can ether:

- Instantiate the first level viewController with the segue, than once you want to add another ViewController (of the same type) with the `UIStoryboard` `instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier:` and give the unique id of the ViewController, and present it

or

- You can just use the `UIStoryboard` `instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier:` every time you want to present the ViewController

Comment: This is indeed working. But the segue behaviour is wierd. Once the user press similar wine they segue as purposed, but if they choose to segue again from the new view they are showen the segue motion twice, and this effect adds up with 2^n. Do you know a way to solve this?